# Evaluating property value from properties file java

Tags: java, properties

In my properties file I am using system variable like this:

```
log4j.appender.RollingFile.File=${workspace.logs}/my.log
```

I am reading the property like this:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(new FileInputStream("logger.properties"));
String label = (String) p.get("log4j.appender.RollingFile.File");
System.out.println(label);
```

The result is:

```
${workspace.logs}/my.log
```

How can I print the result with the evaluated variable? e.g.

`C:/logs/my.log` ?

**EDITED**

I believe that I can do it in regex - as some suggested - so the perfect solution will be how to replace ${..} content with System.property

Comment: You'll have to program that yourself: look for a property named `workspace.logs`. `java.util.Properties` has no built-in capability for evaluating `${...}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java doesn't do this replacement automatically, they are just treated as strings. You will have to do the variable replace by `System.getenv()`.

Before that you will have to recognise and take the variable out using regex or some other mechanism.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{([0-9a-zA-Z.@]+)}");  
Matcher m = p.matcher(label);

if(m.find())
{
     String var = m.group();
     String envVar = var.replace("${","").replace("}","");
     label = label.replace(var,System.getenv(envVar));
}
```

Please note that above code assumes you have only one variable in a line other wise you will have to use a while loop instead of if. Also note that above code may not be syntactically right as I don't have any java IDE with me.

Comment: This is my question - how do you suggest to do it?

Comment: For your convenience I have added a sample code on how it can be done, but you may have to fix some syntax errors, but you get the general idea.

Comment: Actually better to add * after the string in the compile

Comment: Yes, \w cannot match a . hence the issue. I changed the regex, this should work for you.

Comment: Also after the last }

Comment: why did you remove the () brackets for groups?

Comment: I tried your new change and it doesnt' work \\$\\{.*\\} doesn't match ${workspace.logs}/my.log

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use .* or what you mentioned. Not sure where you are verifying, but .* will match everything in the world. Seems you have never worked with regex. check this http://regexr.com?37mtn   However it is good if you could find solution for your problem in whatever way.

Comment: the problem is that it will replace all the characters after the brackets as well

Comment: please check the link I shared. It doesn't replace because we have a brace in the end. Anyway, what ever works for you.

Answer (score 1):

First we have to find what is inside ${ }. after extracting it, replace the whole thing to the value from environment property(hoping that the **workspace.logs** is a Env Variable

)...
to get that we can use

```
System.getenv()
```

and then we can just replace the same using replace method. And this should be done in a loop in case there are multiple env_variable Occurrences

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(new FileInputStream("c:\\log4j.properties"));
String label = (String) p.get("log4j.appender.RollingFile.File");
int firstIndex=label.indexOf("${");
int lastIndex=label.indexOf("}");
String tempKey =label.substring(firstIndex+2,lastIndex);
String tempValue =System.getenv(tempKey);
label=label.replaceFirst("\\$\\{((?s).*)\\}",tempValue);
System.out.println(label);
```

Will give you output as

```
c:/log/my.log
```

Comment: What if I have more than one enviortnment property?

Comment: @Dejel I have mentioned it in my answer itself... I just gave that part to yourself to do..:)

Answer (score 0):

For a very quick and dirty solution you can even use a replacement loop, but that won't account for escaping the placeholder delimiters (what if you someday come up with a literal `${foo}` in your values?). I wrote a simple Lexer/Parser couple by hand to solve a similar issue and it's not a very complex task.

However I suggest you encapsulate the first stage in a template engine in order to play with different implementations. The template engine must be used to create an intermediate text that you will then use like this:

```
// Load the bindings from your configuration
Map<String, Object> bindings = loadBindings();
Template tpl = new Template("log4j.properties");
tpl.bind(bindings);
tpl.compile();

Properties resolvedConfiguration = new Properties();
Reader in = new StringReader(tpl.getText());
resolvedConfiguration.load(in);
```

Unfortunately I was not able to find a template engine configurable enough to be adapted to my needs for placeholder delimiters and variables resolution, and had to write my own, but was an easy task (a couple hours of work) because the language is not complex.

Answer (score 0):

If the you have set the system variable properly,then You would be able to use just

```
${sys:workspace.logs}
```

to get the expected output.

Mentioned in http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html

So Actually you need to write log4j.appender.RollingFile.File=${sys:workspace.logs}/my.log

and problem solved.